# I can't see my skin or anyone else's in 1.12.1 Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This morning I was having some issues with Minecraft. I had launched MC, but it wasn't showing up and I couldn't figure out how to get Minecraft up. I had fixed that after a while, but now Minecraft won't even load my skin.

Everyone is either a Steve or an Alex. I checked the skin server to see if it was down; the website said it was working fine. I've asked friends to see if they could see other skins. They said yes, that they could.

I'm confused, and I don't know what to do.
Skins aren't working in single player nor multiplayer. My MC version is 1.12.1, the latest update.

Just checked again; skins still aren't working. There's no crashes or anything. MC just won't show me skins. Please help!

Comment: Is it still the same? Could you try reinstalling Minecraft or launching 1.12?

Answer (score -2):

Click pause and go onto skins. It should be in your favourites if you've previously worn it or maybe you've accidentally uninstalled the skin. In that case go into the store and get it back/redownload it.

Comment: That's the PE version...